# Как в запросе указать время на час больше

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть запрос вычисляющий среднее значение за определенный час, каким образом можно сделать так чтобы время показывалось на час больше, но среднее значение оставалось тем же самым 2022.05.19 00:00 показывалось 2022.05.19 01:00 и так с каждым часом, но чтобы при этом среднее значение оставалось таким же

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0) as Дата,AVG(Fe_Ka) AS Среднее FROM Results1 
WHERE DateMeasure between '20220514 00:00' and '20220515 00:00'
GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0)
  ORDER BY DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0)
```

[image: Таблица]

Comment: *каким образом можно сделать так чтобы время показывалось на час больше, но среднее значение оставалось тем же самым* Ну эта... прибавить час при выводе значения, но не прибавлять при расчёте среднего.

Comment: и как прибавить при выводе?

Comment: Ну вроде как DATEADD() Вы используете в запросе - вот ей и прибавляйте.

Answer (score 0):

Так точно получится:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0) as Дата,
            AVG(Fe_Ka) AS Среднее
    FROM Results1 
    WHERE DateMeasure between '20220514 00:00' and '20220515 00:00'
    GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0)
)
SELECT  [Дата]
        ,[Среднее]
        ,DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [Дата]) AS [Дата + час]
ORDER BY [Дата]
```

Так короче, но не уверен что отработает, надо пробовать(отпишись по результатам проверки):

```
SELECT  DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0) as Дата,
        DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [Дата]) AS [Дата + час],
        AVG(Fe_Ka) AS Среднее
FROM Results1 
WHERE DateMeasure between '20220514 00:00' and '20220515 00:00'
GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, DateMeasure), 0), DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [Дата])
```